# Validate File Type in ReactJS using Filepond

Tags: reactjs, validation, file-upload, file-type, filepond

I have implemented file upload in ReactJS successfully using Yii2 framework and ReactJS. But I will love to validate file type of file before upload. I have come across [this](https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/patterns/plugins/file-validate-type/) and I have tried implementing it as:

```javascript
<FilePond
    ref={ref => this.pond = ref}
    files={this.state.coverfiles}
    acceptedFileTypes={['images/*']}
    fileValidateTypeDetectType={(source, type) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        
        resolve(type);
     })
    }
    onupdatefiles={(fileItems) => {
          // Set current file objects to this.state
          this.setState({
              coverfiles: fileItems.map(fileItem => fileItem.file)
          });
      }}
    required={true} 
    name={'coverfiles'} 
    //instantUpload={this.state.sumitted}
    allowImageCrop={true}
    allowMultiple={false} 
    processFile={false}
    
    labelIdle={'Drag and Drop your Cover Add Picture or <span class="filepond--label-action"> Browse </span>'}
    
    >
</FilePond>
```

I need to do this in different cases for images, audio files and video files and I do not know how to resolve the particular file type.

Comment: Have you registered the plugin using the `registerPlugin` function?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, the browser supplies the mime type of the file so all you have to do is allow image/audio and video types like so:

```
acceptedFileTypes={['image/*', 'audio/*', 'video/*']}
```

The `fileValidateTypeDetectType` function is only needed if the browser is making an error in detecting the mime type. In which case you `resolve` the correct type (or call `reject(reason)` to cancel.

Comment: that was the very first thing I did. If you look in my code, you will see a line before the fileValidate that is suppose to check whether the accepted file type is image

Comment: I wonder if its simply because you've specified images/* instead of image/* ?

Comment: I have chanaged that and it doesnt work still. so that is not the issue

Comment: Have you tried logging out `source` and seeing whats what?

Answer (score 0):

I haven’t attempted using the file-type-validation plugin but I do know It’s possible to do general pre-upload validation if you set a *server* attribute on FilePond and override the *process* function. Since a File object is exposed as a parameter to that function, you can query the file.type to get the MIME type as a string and reject.

I needed to override this for some other cleanup I needed in order to conform to my API so this just became the natural spot for all my pre-upload validation (file size, name duplication, etc).

What that roughly looks like in practice is:

```
<FilePond
    allowMultiple
    server={
             {  process: (fieldName, file, metadata, load, error, progress, abort) => {
                    if (file.type.includes('image')) {
                        error(new Error('Invalid file type'));
                    } else {
                        load(file.name);
                    }
                }
             }
           }
/>
```

Documentation on that is here: https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/patterns/api/server/#introduction

Also, file.type validation isn’t a perfect method to determine a file’s type since it doesn’t read the byte stream, just parses based on extension. See the advice on MDN about using File.type here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/type

Hope that helps!